# Changing backgroundColor in Swift, Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I know the code to change the backgroundColor in iOS is something to this extent:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
```

But for some reason, I am getting an "Unexpected declaration" error.

Anybody know why?

This is the file I am dealing with, ViewController.swift. It is literally just a new single-view app template from Xcode 6.

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  backgroundColor
//
//  Created by Frank Barrett on 11/21/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Frank Barrett. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

The error is

> /Users/frank/Dropbox/code/ios/backgroundColor/backgroundColor/ViewController.swift:13:5: Expected ?>declaration

Comment: That code should work. Where do you have that code? Show it in its context. Also post the actual error message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You put your code in the wrong place.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // This space is only for declarations.

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        // Put this setup code in the viewDidLoad method.
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok that makes much more sense. Thank you!